# Maven war plugin does not included classes from project

Tags: spring, war, maven-plugin

Im trying to generate war file with maven war plugin, but after unpacing war file (witch command jar -xvf file.war in windows) it looking like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xqxQ.png)
and does not contain class files.

My pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
             <warName>crud</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

My project structure:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtu27.png)

To get a war file I enter command "mvn clean install" and after that "mvn war:war" in the folder with project.

Why I don't have a class file in WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
mvn compile war:war -P TEST
```

`-P TEST` is for setting TEST profile as active. In my case `compile` was key.